# Wired connection keeps disconnected

Tags: 16.04, networking, ethernet, connection

So, I installed ubuntu amd64 16.04. The wired connection keeps disconnected. The only way it will be back again is if I reconnect it manually in the panel. But, after a minute or two, it is disconnected again. This problem also occurs in Linux mint cinnamon 18.2. But, somehow it didnt happen in my previous minimal install ubuntu.

My router is Huawei HG8245A if that helps.

edit : result of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3; uname -a`

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.   RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 09)  
      Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. P8 series motherboard [1043:8505]  
      Kernel driver in use: r8169  
      Kernel modules: r8169  
Linux dedi-ubuntu 4.10.0-28-generic #32~16.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 20 10:19:48   UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

edit : result of `sudo apt install r8168-dkms` for first time, then I run it again for second time.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  dkms
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  dkms r8168-dkms
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 62 not upgraded.
Need to get 151 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1.374 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y\
Get:1 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 dkms all 2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11.3 [66,1 kB]
Get:2 http://id.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 r8168-dkms all 8.041.00-1 [85,0 kB]
Fetched 151 kB in 2s (61,2 kB/s)      
Selecting previously unselected package dkms.
(Reading database ... 175107 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../dkms_2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11.3_all.deb ...
Unpacking dkms (2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package r8168-dkms.
Preparing to unpack .../r8168-dkms_8.041.00-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking r8168-dkms (8.041.00-1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Setting up dkms (2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11.3) ...
Setting up r8168-dkms (8.041.00-1) ...
Loading new r8168-8.041.00 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 4.10.0-28-generic
Building initial module for 4.10.0-28-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.10.0-28-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.041.00/build/make.log for more information.
```

edit : second time

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
r8168-dkms is already the newest version (8.041.00-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 62 not upgraded.
```

edit : the make.log if it helps

```
DKMS make.log for r8168-8.041.00 for kernel 4.10.0-28-generic (x86_64)
Min Agu 27 03:14:41 WIB 2017
make: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-28-generic'
  LD      /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.041.00/build/built-in.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.041.00/build/r8168_n.o
/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.041.00/build/r8168_n.c: In function ‘rtl8168_fix_features’:
/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.041.00/build/r8168_n.c:4212:30: error: ‘NETIF_F_ALL_CSUM’ undeclared (first use in this function)
                 features &= ~NETIF_F_ALL_CSUM;
                              ^
/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.041.00/build/r8168_n.c:4212:30: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.041.00/build/r8168_n.c: In function ‘rtl8168_start_xmit’:
/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.041.00/build/r8168_n.c:24599:12: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘trans_start’
         dev->trans_start = jiffies;
            ^
scripts/Makefile.build:294: recipe for target '/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.041.00/build/r8168_n.o' failed
make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.041.00/build/r8168_n.o] Error 1
Makefile:1524: recipe for target '_module_/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.041.00/build' failed
make: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.041.00/build] Error 2
make: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-28-generic'
```

edit : sudo dpkg -i r8168-dkms_8.043.02-1_all.deb

```
    (Reading database ... 175175 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack r8168-dkms_8.043.02-1_all.deb ...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 8.041.00
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Unpacking r8168-dkms (8.043.02-1) over (8.041.00-1) ...
Setting up r8168-dkms (8.043.02-1) ...
Loading new r8168-8.043.02 DKMS files...
Building only for 4.10.0-28-generic
Building initial module for 4.10.0-28-generic
Done.

r8168:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.10.0-28-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod......

Backing up initrd.img-4.10.0-28-generic to /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-28-generic.old-dkms
Making new initrd.img-4.10.0-28-generic
(If next boot fails, revert to initrd.img-4.10.0-28-generic.old-dkms image)
update-initramfs....

DKMS: install completed.
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.10.0-28-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin for module i915
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3; uname -a` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 , I have edit the post.

Comment: Try out the vendor driver by `sudo apt install r8168-dkms`. If it doesn't build (Canonical didn't update it for the 4.10 kernel), I'll give you another link.

Comment: You need another version, see the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install the vendor driver. Since it is not updated for the 4.10 kernel in `xenial` repos, you can install it from `zesty`.

Run

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/r8168/r8168-dkms_8.043.02-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i r8168-dkms_8.043.02-1_all.deb
```

Comment: Thanks, it works now. Also, I change the MTU for my wired connection to 9000. IDK if it helps or not. Will this method work in Linux Mint 18.2?. Also, do you know why my wired connection didnt have this problem in minimal ubuntu?

Comment: It should work on Mint too. This is a kernel issue. Thi in-tree `r8169` claims to support all`r8168`, but it is not always the case. It may be fixed in newer kernels. Also maybe some new firmware was required by the new kernel. If you gave `dmesg | grep r8169` without `r8168-dkms` installed, it would be possible to tell. But there was no warning like the `i915`. So it is unlikely. The vendor diver is always a workaround.