# Ethernet connection Issue on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, drivers, compiling

I have the same issue as this post [Ethernet connection Issues on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/819376/ethernet-connection-issues-on-ubuntu-16-04)
I tried heynnema advice but after restarting my laptop's Internet connection was not established.

Output from terminal:

```
~$ lspci -nnk | grep -e 0200 -e 0280 -A2
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 31)
Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:1810]
Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
Subsystem: Dell RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1028:0791]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

But Synaptic shows me that r8169-dkms is installed. Next i tried to reinstall r8169-dkms through Synaptic. As a result i got this:

```
 (Читання бази даних ... на дану мить встановлено 285542 файли та каталоги.)
 Приготування до розпакування .../r8168-dkms_8.041.00-1_all.deb ...


Deleting module version: 8.041.00 completely from the DKMS tree.
Done.
Розпакування r8168-dkms (8.041.00-1) над (8.041.00-1)...
Налаштовування r8168-dkms (8.041.00-1) ...
Loading new r8168-8.041.00 DKMS files...
Building only for 4.10.0-40-generic
Building initial module for 4.10.0-40-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/r8168-dkms.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.10.0-40-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.041.00/build/make.log for more information.
```

Text from /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.041.00/build/make.log:

```
DKMS make.log for r8168-8.041.00 for kernel 4.10.0-40-generic (x86_64)
четвер, 23 листопада 2017 16:30:07 +0200
 make: входимо до каталогу «/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-40-generic»
  LD      /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.041.00/build/built-in.o
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.041.00/build/r8168_n.o
  /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.041.00/build/r8168_n.c: In function ‘rtl8168_fix_features’:
  /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.041.00/build/r8168_n.c:4212:30: error: ‘NETIF_F_ALL_CSUM’ undeclared (first use in this function)
             features &= ~NETIF_F_ALL_CSUM;
                          ^
/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.041.00/build/r8168_n.c:4212:30: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.041.00/build/r8168_n.c: In function ‘rtl8168_start_xmit’:
/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.041.00/build/r8168_n.c:24599:12: error: ‘struct net_device’ has no member named ‘trans_start’
     dev->trans_start = jiffies;
        ^
scripts/Makefile.build:294: спроба виконання рецепта для мети «/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.041.00/build/r8168_n.o» зазнала невдачі
make[1]: *** [/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.041.00/build/r8168_n.o] Помилка 1
Makefile:1524: спроба виконання рецепта для мети «_module_/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.041.00/build» зазнала невдачі
make: *** [_module_/var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.041.00/build] Помилка 2
make: Залишаю каталог "/usr/src/linux-headers-4.10.0-40-generic"
```

If I understand correctly, make can't compile driver. How to fix it?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/950123/wired-connection-keeps-disconnected

Comment: Made as in post. Got such picture after lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3; uname -a :
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
 Subsystem: Dell RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1028:0791]
 Kernel driver in use: r8168
 Kernel modules: r8168
Linux trustdark-Vostro-15-3568 4.10.0-40-generic #44~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 9 15:37:44 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Still dont have wired internet.

Comment: It is obvious for me to use mac-cloning, so i wrote right mac-address in appropriate field in network manager. Can be here issue?

Comment: You probably used an invalid MAC address. Remove your entry, reboot, and you should be ok.